# How do I set up rpy2?

Tags: python, r

Hi I just download rpy2 and Python 2.6. When I try to run some of example code I found on the internet, I got this error. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how can I fix it? Thanks.

```
import rpy2.robjects as RO

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import rpy2.robjects as RO
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    "This might be because R.exe is nowhere in your Path.")
RuntimeError: Unable to determine R version from the registery.Calling the command 'R RHOME' does not return anything.
This might be because R.exe is nowhere in your Path.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This might be because R.exe is nowhere
>   in your Path

This sounds like a big clue. Check the value of `%PATH%` in your Windows environment. I'd expect this to contain the location of `R.EXE` (probably something like `C:\Programs\R\R-2.8.0\bin`).

Comment: This page  describes how to set the path: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm